# HttpCore4.4 How to stop HttpServer?

Tags: java, httpserver, apache-httpcomponents

Java: Apache HttpComponents - HttpServer

server is starting...

```
final HttpServer server = ServerBootstrap.bootstrap().create();
server.start();
```

but how to stop server programmatically and correctly?

For me not clear what for this:

> server.shutdown(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

I am going to close my app but don't want to do `System.exit(0);`

Answer (score 0):

I think a shutdown hook should be your best option.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        server.shutdown(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
});
```

Comment: I see. It the same in examples. Even without hooks server.shutdown(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); can`t to stop programm and app process still present. It mean some thread still exist.

Comment: server#shutdown should terminate the listener and all worker threads but there might be other execution threads still running. You can find out what threads are still running by doing a thread dump